# Django urls.py problem passing variables

Tags: django, url

I have an app called portfolio and I am trying to map out the pages so that i end up with a fixed area that always exists called 'gallery'. I have set this up and it's working fine, but the gallery items are mapped to page_type areas, such as 'images', 'videos' etc so I wanted my root urls.py to detect this and then send t the correct view but I cant figure out how to do it

root urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

 (r'^(?P<page_type>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', include('portfolio.urls')),
 (r'^gallery/', include('portfolio.urls')),

 (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root)
)
```

portfolio urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('portfolio.views',
 #(r'^(?P<gallery_type>\d+)/$', 'index'),
 (r'^page/(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/$', 'index'),
 (r'^(?P<page_category>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', 'category_index'),
 (r'^(?P<page_category>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/$', 'category_index'),
 (r'^$', 'index'),
)
```

Is it even possible? And how? I can't find any info on passing the matching expressions etc.

PLease help. Thanks :)

A friend has pointed out that I could go directly to the views rather than go via the apps urls.py by doing something like this
[code]
(r'^(?P[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(?P[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', 'portfolio.views.detail'),
[/code]

and then accessing it using:
[code]
def detail(request, page_type, page_name):
   ...
[/code]

Comment: Please cleanup your question the tags you have used are incorrect

Comment: I've cleaned up the code, but need more information before I can answer the question. What do you want your urls to look like? What will they do.

Comment: Daniel, can i just say, you rock!

Comment: I would like the urls to look like this:
site/gallery/    - displays all items when you click on one the url is dependant on the type of item is is so it could be:
site/images/ or
site/videos/
where 'site' is the website address.

'images' or 'videos' or '..other..' are dynamic types created in the admin.

Answer (score 5):

You have to move `(r'^gallery/', include('portfolio.urls')),` BEFORE `(r'^(?P<page_type>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', include('portfolio.urls')),` because the page type regex will also match 'gallery/' and the patterns are apllied in the order as they are defined!

Comment: Cheers dude. I will move that higher up :D I guess admin should also be higher up?

Comment: Yes, because `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` will match any alphanumeric combination (also 'admin').